# How strong are werewolves in the "Teen Wolf" TV series?

Tags: teen-wolf

I have just started *Teen Wolf* and got to wonder about the strength level of werewolves in this universe. What feats of strengths have been shown?

Comment: Why spoil it for yourself?

Comment: You ask a LOT of questions just like this. Is there a cross-universe cage match you're taking bets on or something?

Comment: No i'm not i read and watch different supernatural stuff and wonder how the powers compare to legends etc

Comment: And i want to spoil it for myself lol

Comment: The only *Teen Wolf* that matters starred Michael J. Fox.

Answer (score 5):

Werewolves in the *Teen Wolf* universe have shown to be stronger than humans, but not *radically* stronger.

For example, in the early seasons, several wolves are shown to play sports (primarily lacrosse), and being a werewolf gives them added strength, speed, agility, etc. They are shown to easily break other players' bones and destroy the lacrosse equipment if they aren't careful. However, they never do anything that is *obviously* supernatural enough to make people question what's going on.

When the werewolves get into fights indoors, they are frequently shown punching through stone pillars or walls, and breaking ropes and restraints that aren't specifically designed for them. On the other hand, jail cells and strong cages are able to restrain them, as are sufficiently strong leather straps (Deaton has these at the vet clinic for just this purpose.)

In a hand-to-hand fight with humans, a werewolf is obviously going to overpower the human, but it's not an instant thing. Styles has been attacked by werewolves and survived: when a werewolf wants to kill a human, it's usually by using their claws, and not brute strength. Though they can easily pick up and toss around a full-sized human, it still takes effort for one of them to beat someone to death.

Also, keep in mind that there are more than one kind of werewolf; there's at least four "degrees" of werewolf: Omega, Beta, Alpha, and True Alpha. Each of those is stronger than the ones listed before it, so e.g. Derek is stronger than any of the other wolves he turned, and

> Scott eventually becomes stronger than every other werewolf shown so far.

Comment: I'd just like to point out, Scott was barely able to keep Liam from falling off the edge of a building under his own strength... but that one girl, the were-coyote, was able to effortlessly lift a tree with one hand in a recent episode.

Comment: Yes, the actual strength of werewolves in the show is "however strong or weak they need to be for good drama." Which is really always the right answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

I kinda disagree. When Scott was getting tortured by that Mexican group, he was wearing steel restraints, which take up to 40,000 pounds of force to break. And that was while Scott was getting tortured with full voltage, which would kill any human there is, so he was greatly weakened at the time.

And he was able to fight the Beast, which was able to cause a mini earthquake with his hands and be able to lift and throw buses, I bet. I would say the Beast is around the hundreds of tons while Scott is around 40 to 50 tons at full strength.

Comment: So the average strength of a heroine in a video game.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post and all but a good example is Derek, after attaining the power of an alpha, when Issac fell Into an empty grave while in an excavator (which toppled over by a weaker werewolf) trapping Issac, Derek hoisted the excavator off the top of the grave, it's unclear the amount of effort Derek actually used, but excavators typically weight on average 30 tons, now I can't see Derek being that strong, but I don't think the creators actually cared or looked into the limitations and the science of what the characters can do or how much they can lift and just thought "this is heavy, let's have this character lift it"

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. You could improve this answer by editing it to include the title of the specific episode you're talking about. And if you could add a relevant screenshot as well, that'd be even better.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be no "base strength" equivalent, as to say "the weakest werewolf can bench at least 800 lbs". If anything, this seems to be a highly "personalized" aspect; in one season 4 or 5 episode, Scott, now a true Alpha, is taking on a humongous werewolf bruiser... and while holding his own, he can't overpower the guy by sheer force, to which this warrior says:

> I see the *eyes* of an Alpha... but where is the *strength* ?

You can see the guy's *sheer size* compared to Scott and Kira here:

[image: Kira fighting Kincaid. Kira is jumping on his shoulders, which leaves the tall Kincaid quite indifferent]

I don't think this was meant as an insult, but a genuine question; the implication is Alphas, regardless of size, are "supposed" to be amongst the physically strongest class of werewolves. This guy, Kincaid, *easily* outweighed Scott by at least 80 lbs, though and was a good deal taller, so it makes logical sense that he would have more physical power due to sheer muscle force. 
Concurrently, though, Scott pointed out that the *true* strength of a werewolf comes from his *pack* and not his body. One can't be sure if this was purely a philosophy, like "We're stronger together", or an actual biological fact, and the more members of a pack, the greater each one's strength becomes by sharing some kind of bond with the others.

The "strength" of an Alpha isn't necessarily muscular though, but in the "spark of power" that places them, in an *evolutionary* sense, somewhat above their fellows. This power, from what I've seen, grants them certain advantages:

- Their wills or hearts are stronger, allowing them to endure more than Betas.
- They can shift into a "beast mode" form, so likely have a more "primal" animal connection.
- They heal more quickly, so their powers are likely more efficient.
- They can heal *others* from the brink of death, though this seems to "sacrifice" the Alpha power. This may just be an extension of the empathic pain-nullifying powers all werewolves have, but it's never stated.
- Their "dominance" can literally stun others, allowing them to exert a type of mental control over lesser wolves, and influence the mood, actions and behaviors of their pack mates. Think of it as a type of "Haki" from *One Piece.* This is shown in how Scott's howl or growl could stop other beings cold; they seemed to detect the "danger" from him on an instinctual level, and react to it.
- They have a limited ability to increase their own physical abilities in the short term, like an adrenaline rush. This was shown in the number of times Scott got a last-minute burst of power to defeat enemies he otherwise shouldn't have been able to. This was also shown when Peter Hale injected himself with adrenalin and fought another Alpha wolf to a standstill.
- They can sense their fellows conditions and presence more keenly than even other wolves could.

The fact that there was a *pack* of Alphas (you'll get to it, not trying to spoil) would indicate a combination of both the aforementioned conditions. Each member was powerful in their own right, with distinct traits. All of the Alphas were *immense* psychical threats by themselves, doing some seemingly impossible stuff, and together there were curb stomping our heroes until... well, you'll see.

Either way, throughout the series, Scott (a True Alpha) and Derek Hale (a Beta, then Alpha, then Beta who gave up his "spark of power" to save his sister's life) showed that their personal strength could grow via training, the trials they faced, and via the connection they felt with their fellows. Added to this is that their attributes would increase when they "shift" into full wolf form, so technically, their "human form", while stronger than average, was *not* them at their all-out strongest (think of it as the difference between "base form Sayian" and "Super Saiyan").

If I had to hazard a guess, I'd say a werewolf is somewhere between 3-5 times stronger, faster and more agile than a well-trained human of the same height and weight, with increased durability and healing factor accounting for why they can cause so much damage. In full wolf form, they could probably go up to 6, so roughly on par with a Kodiak bear. This is just an educated guess based on the feats I've seen performed in show, though.